# "function not found" error when making both GET and POST requests to a Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm getting a

```
Script function not found: doGet
```

OR

```
Script function not found: doPost
```

when I GET/POST to my Google script:

```
function doGet(e){return ContentService.createTextOutput("User says")}

function doPost(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<form action='http://www.example.com/users/gmail_permission/' method='post' id='foo'>" + 
    "<input type='hidden' name='gmail' value='getEmail()' >" +
    "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='e.parameter.user_id' >" +    
    "</form>" +
    "<script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>");
}

function getEmail() {
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

The weird thing is I'll get the above error when I visit the Webapp URL on my browser. But when I use Hurl.it, I just get redirected to Google Drive. But when I 'Test web app for your latest code.' on google.script.com, the GET response works fine.

Pretty lost as to what is going on.... here is my script:

```
 https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz0XGeoEuP4V6W60N7yP-dDiLltPefxmqzhMJurnGzOhPfqA_er/exec
```

Here are the GETs

```
 FROM Hurl.it - GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&followup=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz0XGeoEuP4V6W60N7yP-dDiLltPefxmqzhMJurnGzOhPfqA_er/exec&continue=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz0XGeoEuP4V6W60N7yP-dDiLltPefxmqzhMJurnGzOhPfqA_er/exec&passive=1209600

 FROM script.google.com: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyCH4Jk7VcEIhE52jIorIBzcghRYAPRuwuzFSHwaWIB/dev

 FROM browser:https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz0XGeoEuP4V6W60N7yP-dDiLltPefxmqzhMJurnGzOhPfqA_er/exec
```

Comment: Have you saved a version and published that version?

Comment: would you show your get and post to the web app

Comment: @Sergeinsas I have saved it and published this version above

Comment: @DavidF I'll add them to the question

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

It's pretty stupid, but apparently saving and republishing your google script web app is not good enough. You need to save a new version and publish the new version to make sure your app gets updated properly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was getting so frustrated with the same problem, and this fixed my issue.

Comment: To add a new version go to ```File -> Manage versions...```

Comment: You don't need to goto manage versions. You can just do Publish>Deploy as Web App>  and select "new" in the project version dropbox. Seriously, Google should get rid of this requirement or atleast warn developers clearly, since its not intuitive.

Comment: I did as the answer suggests but it still doesn't work.  Broken garbage.  I don't think google cares about this.

Comment: same here, I wonder why the super smart google guys didn't get that :p

Comment: wow. I cant believe this is the answer. thats so frustrating. thank you

Comment: I upvoted this around 2 years ago. Today I tried to create a new app, and couldn't get it to work, and this issue had me stuck for over an hour until I found this post again... Wish I could upvote it again!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have saved the project, otherwise you can face the same issue. I faced the same because I didn't save the file before deploying.