# doGet Error found

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

I created Google Script. Now when I run it in Google Script, it runs perfectly and does the file movement to folder. Also I can create Web App Deployment for publishing. Now when I try to run the Script in Browser by entering the link, it returns error : Script function not found: doGet. Please tell me what is wrong in my Script. My requirement is that I had a website at www.rohansarker.com where I want to insert HTML or JavaScript or PHP so that the Google Script runs from my Website on opening. Please help me how I can design the same.

Comment: I don't think your comment is related to GWT. Google Apps Script is something else entirely. I think your question may have been answered here anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617138/google-apps-script-function-not-found-doget

Comment: The reply was not satisfactory. I wrote an existing Google Script (.gs) which moves a file from one folder to another folder and the script runs absolutely well in Google Script. The problem is that the deployed web application does not run on opening in a browser and throws the doGet error. I need to know the following: (1) What modification in Google Script I need to do in Google Script Window. (2) What html code or php code or javascript code I need to write in my webpage www.rohansarker.com so that while opening my site, the file movement by Google Script will be done in Google Drive.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. I suggest you provide more information in the question, preferably some example code if you want someone to help you.

Comment: just read the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web   a webapp must include a doGet function and will be called by the deployment url after at least one version has been created.