# Google Script function not found: onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a sheet that sends an email once a line item's column H has been marked as "Complete". Recently, the code has stopped working and I am getting this error:

> Script function not found: onEdit

Execution Transcript

```
[18-09-10 11:59:29:910 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:910 PDT] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:910 PDT] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:911 PDT] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:911 PDT] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:911 PDT] Session.getActiveUser() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:911 PDT] User.getEmail() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:912 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[18-09-10 11:59:29:920 PDT] Starting execution
[18-09-10 11:59:29:927 PDT] Execution failed: Script function not found: onEdit [0 seconds total runtime]
```

Here's the code:

```
function installTriggers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  deleteTriggers(); 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSheetEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendConfirmationMail').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function onSheetEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
  //if the most recently edited cell doesn't contain a "Completed" and it's not the column of your "status" then we're not concerned with it. 
  if (e.value == "Completed" && e.range.getColumn() == 9 )
  {
    SendCompletedMail(e);
  }
}

function SendCompletedMail(e)
{
  var ss, cc, sendername, subject, message, value, textbody, sender;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentrow = e.range.getRow();    
  cc = "email@abc.com";
  sendername = "Request handler";
  subject = "Request has been Completed';
  message = "Your request has been completed.<br>Thank you for submitting your request.";

  //This is the submitter's email address from the sheet - make sure this column matches the email address column of the submitter
  sender = ss.getRange(currentrow, 7).getValue().toString();
  Logger.log(sender)

  textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");

  GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, {
      cc: cc,
      name: sendername,
      htmlBody: message
    });
}
```

What is causing the `onEdit()` function to not be found?

Comment: can you add the `execution script` message please

Comment: There's no `onEdit()` function in your script

Comment: Edited - added execution transcript

Comment: coul you share the spreadsheet I could take a look at it directly.?

Comment: There is no `onEdit()` function in your script. However, you also do not call any `onEdit()` functions you just have an installable trigger (might want to check if it's still correctly defined). Is this the entire code?

Comment: Have you tried to republish the new version of your app as described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617138/google-apps-script-function-not-found-doget)?