# Google apps script(Error script function not found doPost )

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Error image on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGF7Z.png)

This is the code in my google web app script and the doPost is defined but I keep getting the same error and my google sheets does not register the input of the user it is "undefined"

```
 // original from: http://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

// Usage
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app 
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version' 
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously) 
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action 
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function


function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput("Success")
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput("Failure")
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId())
```

;
}

[Google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFRS8.png)

This is another error that I do not understand. In my html code i have defined my users input exactly as it is shown on each of the cells I have created in the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617138/google-apps-script-function-not-found-doget). Saving and republishing your google script web app might be the problem. You need to save a new version and publish the new version to make sure your app gets updated properly.

Also from this [blog](http://googleappscripting.com/script-function-not-found-doget/):

> The same problem can arise if you are sending a POST request but you don’t have a POST request handler. Then you will see the error, “Script function not found: doPost” error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a POST with JSON in the body of the request, if you're able to find the link to the author of the [original code](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/), he updated it slightly.

```
var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```